# Deleting a key for an object inside a replicated object also deletes existing objects

Tags: javascript

```
var origin = { a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: 3 } }; // origin object

var copy_obj = { ...origin } // or Object.assign({}, origin.b)

delete copy_obj.b.c; // delete copy object

console.log(origin) // { a: 1, b: { d: 3 } };
```

I'm studying the invariant nature of things.

However, the above example shows that you want to delete the b.c. element of copy_obj. But the origin is also deleted.

Why is this happening?

Comment: The spread syntax does a shallow copy (only one level deep), so `copy_obj.b` is a reference to `origin.b`.

Answer (score 8):

`Object.assign({}, origin.b)` or spread syntax `{...obj}` performs a shallow copy. So the object stored in property `b` of origin is not cloned i.e it maintains a reference to the object being nested.

Use the following to make a deep clone.

```js
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

```js
var origin = { a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: 3 } }; // origin object

var copy_obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(origin));

delete copy_obj.b.c; 

console.log(origin)
```

**Note: This only works for objects that can be serialized**

For example:

```js
// Object having functions
const obj= {
  a: 1,
  b: () => {return 2}
}


const copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));

// property `b` won't be copied as it is a function and can't be serialized.
console.log(copy)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the JSON trick only works for objects that can be serialized. In other words, no cyclical references and no functions.